# Java FX инициализация полей

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу свое первое приложение на JavaFX - чат. Столкнулся с проблемой обновления данных в компоненте сцены JavaFX - textArea. Этот компонент инициализируется только один раз при загрузке сцены из FXML файла в классе контроллере методом void initialize().
При работе чата я хотел сделать традиционную модель MVC. Идея проста - контроллер(клиент) меняет модель данных и параллельно заставляет view часть(конкретно переменную textArea)обновляться данными, вытягиваемые из модели. Но не тут то было, застрял на реализации обновления данных в textArea(где отображаются сообщения пользователей). Переменную textArea, как я понял, нельзя обновлять вне метода void initialize(). 
В голове крутится вариант каждый раз обновлять всю сцену при обновлении модели, но ведь это затратно...
Может быть, кто-нибудь подскажет как решаются проблемы такого характера. Буду очень благодарен

```
    public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TextArea textChatArea;


    @FXML
    void initialize() throws InterruptedException {
        setMessage("Hello");
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        textChatArea.setText(message);
    }
}
public class Model {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        controller.setMessage("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: textArea.setText();

Comment: Если я пытаюсь сделать это вне метода void initialize() класса контроллера FXML файла, то я ловлю исключение nullPointerException

Comment: код будет нелишним

Comment: Код добавил. Класс модель пытается изменить переменную textArea. Но выдает исключение nullPointerException

Comment: Очень вероятно, что оно не находит textChatArea из fxml. Приведите код fxml

Comment: В Group должно быть указано fx:controller="Controller"

Comment: Она там есть. Ведь первая инициализация проходит. Которая находится в методе void initialize(). И текст отображается в окне. А вот уже внешняя попытка изменить эту переменную приводит к исключению. Я подозреваю, что эту переменную можно менять только в методе void initialize()....

Comment: А почему у вас два метода main?

Comment: Просто создал два главных потока. Сначала один поток создает окно со сценой. Потом запускаю модель(второй поток), и она пытается изменить textArea. Это тест для проверки, не само приложение... И каждый класс в разных файлах

Comment: Вижу, что в разных. Сделайте Model потоком, и создайте его после  primaryStage.show();

Comment: Может, аннотацию @FXML добавить?

Comment: к чему аннотацию?

Comment: К setMessage().

Comment: Сделал по вашей рекомендации, ошибка выходит та же. Первая попытка инициализации проходит, вторая(из класса модель) - нет

Comment: и аннотация тоже не действенна, к сожалению

Comment: Приведите код sample.fxml, в методе initialize() на сколько я помню не должно быть никаких выбрасываемых исключений. И какого именно результата вы ждете от main метода из Model, который к FX не имеет никакого отношения и вызывает `null.setText`?

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за отклик! Решил данную проблему путем ввода таких переменных как "property". Суть их такова, что при "bind" такой переменной к объекту нашего поля(к примеру, textArea) все изменения коснувшиеся property переменной сразу же отразятся на объекте поля.